# Error "not valid choice" when dropdown populated using ajax

Tags: ajax, 9

I've searched the other similar answer but still no luck.

I have content type *Station* with field *Province* and *City*.

Form alter:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'node_station_form') {
//    kint($form);
    $form['field_province']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => 'mymodule_callback_example',
      'wrapper' => 'edit-field-city-wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
    ];

    $form['field_city']['#attributes']['id'] = 'edit-field-city-wrapper';

    $options = ['_none' => '- None -'];

    $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $province = $user_input["field_province"] ?? NULL;

    if ($province) {
      if ($province === 'province_a') {
        $cities = [
          'province-a-city-1' => 'Province A City 1',
          'province-a-city-2' => 'Province A City 2',
          'province-a-city-3' => 'Province A City 3',
        ];
      }
      else {
        $cities = [
          'province-b-city-1' => 'Province B City 1',
          'province-b-city-2' => 'Province B City 2',
          'province-b-city-3' => 'Province B City 3',
        ];
      }
      $options += $cities;
    }

    $form['field_city']['widget']['#options'] = $options;
  }
}

function mymodule_callback_example($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['field_city'];
}
```

The dropdown City successfully populate based on Province, but when I click submit form, there are error "The value you selected is not a valid choice"

[image]

What did I miss?

**Update**

Solved by following this [link](https://chromatichq.com/insights/dynamic-default-and-allowed-values-list-fields-drupal-8). It add `allowed_values_function` to the field storage.

Added to field storage

```
allowed_values_function: 'mymodule_allowed_values_function'
```

and

```
default_value_callback: 'mymodule_default_value_callback'
```

to field `field.field.node.station.field_city.yml`.

The callback function:

```
function mymodule_allowed_values_function(FieldStorageConfig $definition, ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL, $cacheable) {
  $empty = ['_none' => t('- None -')];
  $cities = [];
  if (!$entity->get('field_province')->isEmpty()) {
    $province = $entity->get('field_province')->value;
    if ($province === 'province_a') {
      $cities = [
        'province-a-city-1' => 'Province A City 1',
        'province-a-city-2' => 'Province A City 2',
        'province-a-city-3' => 'Province A City 3',
      ];
    }
    else {
      $cities = [
        'province-b-city-1' => 'Province B City 1',
        'province-b-city-2' => 'Province B City 2',
        'province-b-city-3' => 'Province B City 3',
      ];
    }
  }
  return $empty + $cities;
}

function mymodule_default_value_callback(ContentEntityInterface $entity, FieldDefinitionInterface $definition) {
  return [
    ['value' => '_none'],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Are those city values in the list of allowed values in the field storage settings? You can not invent new field values in a form alter.

Comment: Field storage settings for city is empty. It would be dynamically populated.

Comment: You can't dynamically invent new values for list-type fields. Take a look at this blog post: https://chromatichq.com/insights/dynamic-default-and-allowed-values-list-fields-drupal-8

Comment: I'll try this `allowed_values_function`.

Comment: Hi @Hudri, thank you so much, that works. I'll update with my code to help others or my future self.